# Compiling multiple files leading to secondary articles in the Appendix

Tags: compiling, overleaf, appendix, multiple-files

I am consolidating three articles into my thesis using Overleaf and I used [this link given on the Overleaf website](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects) as a base framework. I have included the additional preamble I added but I keep running into multiple problems:

1. All articles after the first keep getting counted as Appendix, so any numbering for the sections in the 2nd and 3rd articles get titled as A.1 Introduction and so on.
2. Page numbering is entirely wonky, it does not count from the beginning continuously to the end, instead it resets at each article.

Hereunder is the code and preamble for the main.tex. I have followed the overleaf structure in the link above for the rest.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[authordate-trad,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{references.bib} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\title{
{Thesis Title}\\
{\large Institution Name}\\
}
\author{Author Name}
\date{September 2023}
\title{Thesis}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract goes here

%\chapter*{Dedication}
%To mum and dad



%\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
%I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction}

\chapter{Chapter 1 Title}
\input{chapters/chapter02}

\chapter{Chapter 2 Title}
\input{chapters/chapter03}

\chapter{Chapter 3 Title}
\input{chapters/chapter04}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/conclusion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE.
I just tried your example by creating the missing files (please remember for your next question to provide a minimal working example which can be copied or downloaded ready to compile. It makes it way easier to answer your question). Anyway, with the code you provided I couldn't replicate your problem. The chapters are correctly counted from 1 to 5.

Comment: Oh and I also don't have the odd page numbering that you mentioned. If you upload an example which actually compiles to the problem you are describing I am sure someone here will have a solution.

Comment: If you have preambles in each chapter, they will need to be removed.  The subfiles package is suppposed to be able to handle (ignore) multiple preambles.